# First power of 2 that has leading decimal digits of 12 in Common Lisp

Tags: performance, math, common-lisp

In the webpage of Rosetta Code (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/First_power_of_2_that_has_leading_decimal_digits_of_12#C) there is the following challenge: Find the first power of 2 that has leading decimal digits of 12.

I have written several versions in Common Lisp, but I fail miserably in terms of performance compared to what other languages report.

The following code is one of the many versions that I have tried.

```
(defun log10 (x) (/ (log x) (log 10)))

(defun first-digits (n l)
    (let* ((len-n (1+ (floor (log10 n))))
           (tens (expt 10 (- len-n l))) )
       (truncate n tens) ))


(defun p (rem n)
    (do* ((len-rem (1+ (floor (log10 rem))))
                (i 0 (1+ i)) 
        (k 1 (* 2 k)) )
       ((= n 0) (1- i))
    (when (= rem (first-digits k len-rem))
        (decf n) )))
```

The performance is really poor, but I refuse to admit that Common Lisp is slower than any competitors. Any idea of how to achieve the run time of a few seconds reported by C#, C++, etc.?

Comment: Well, for comparing to other languages, maybe start by translating the implementations in other languages -- maybe it has more to do with the algorithm than the language. About the method shown in the problem statement here, my advice is to avoid floating point operations such as `log` when working with integers; you can run into subtly incorrect behavior due to results being very slightly more or less than exact values. Finally, look for ways to compute the leading digits without carrying along all the digits. E.g. can you express leading digits of 2^(n + 1) in terms of leading digits of 2^n?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer which is now substantially equivalent to yours (based on the idea in [this maths SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006181), but a little more general and a little more optimized.  In particular:

- it lets you specify both the number you want to raise to a power;
- it lets you specify the base you want to work in (so not just 10);
- it knows that `(log x b)` is the log of `x` in base `b`;
- it computes the log you need just once;
- it reorganizes some of the float operations to avoid overflows (at some point your version will call `(expt 10 n)` with a big enough `n` thay you'll get a floating point overflow.

I think (in fact I'm reasonably sure) that the remaining thing that is making it slow is float consing.  It ought to be possible to prevail upon a compiler to avoid this, and I spent a small amount of time trying but to no avail.

Anyway, here it is.

```
(defun p (L n &key (b 2) (base 10.0d0))
  ;; nth occurence of power of b with leading digits L in base:
  ;; returns power (p below)
  (let ((k-1 (floor (log L base)))      ;(digits of L in base) - 1
        (logb (log (float b 1.0d0) base))) ;log of b in base
    (do* ((p 0 (1+ p))                  ;power
          (d 1 (floor (expt base (+ (rem (* p logb) 1) k-1)))) ;digits
          (c (if (= L 1) 1 0)            ;count of hits
             (if (= L d) (1+ c) c)))
         ((= c n) p))))
```

---

Below is an earlier, useless answer: I've left it for posterity.

Note that the first part what's below deals with only the two-leading-digit case because I didn't bother looking at the original rosetta code thing: see the end for a generalisation.

First of all to pull out the first two decimal digits of something, you want to start by divide it by a suitable power of 10 that the result is a two digit number.  That means taking logs, but you can cheat: if you know the number of bits, b, in the number then the number is 2^b + change (assuming it's a positive integer), and knowing the number of bits is very very quick.  And then if 10^x = 2^y then x = y/(log_2 10) where log_2 is log base 2.  And this is a constant.

So you can write this function after fiddling around with pen and paper for a bit:

```
(defun leading-two-digits (n)
  (truncate (truncate n (expt 10 (1- (truncate (integer-length n)
                                               (load-time-value (log 10 2))))))
            10))
```

Note the use of `load-time-value` to compute the `(log 10 2)` just once.  And note also that this relies on either having correct integer arithmetic or at least a function which will tell you what the number of bits in a number would be if you did have.

So now

```
> (leading-two-decimal-digits 59468049869823987435)
5
9
```

OK, looks good (extensive testing...).

So now you just need to start from 1 and successively multiply by the base, looking for the leading two digits being what you care about.  As a hack if the base is 2 you can just left shift: my original function assumed the base was 2 and always left shifted, this one has a configurable base but still special-cases 2, which I suspect may no longer help at all.

```
(defun nth-ld-power (n &key (b 2) (leading 1) (second 2))
  ;; iterate is tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/, also should be in
  ;; Quicklisp
  (iterate looking ((v 1)               ;value
                    (p 0)               ;power (so we can report it)
                    (c 0))              ;hit count
    (multiple-value-bind (d1 d2) (leading-two-decimal-digits v)
      (if (and (= d1 leading) (= d2 second))
          (let ((c+ (1+ c)))
            (if (= c+ n)
                (values v p)
              (looking (if (= b 2) (ash v 1) (* v b)) (1+ p) c+)))
        (looking (if (= b 2) (ash v 1) (* v b)) (1+ p) c)))))
```

Again you would want to deal with the multiple-leading-digits case by passing a list of leading digits, but.

OK, so now:

```
> (time (nth-ld-power 2))
Timing the evaluation of (nth-ld-power 2)

User time    =        0.000
System time  =        0.000
Elapsed time =        0.000
Allocation   = 2848 bytes
0 Page faults
GC time      =        0.000
1208925819614629174706176
80

> (time (nth-ld-power 10))
Timing the evaluation of (nth-ld-power 10)

User time    =        0.000
System time  =        0.000
Elapsed time =        0.000
Allocation   = 40704 bytes
0 Page faults
GC time      =        0.000
124330809102446660538845562036705210025114037699336929360115994223289874253133343883264
286
```

OK, this is too quick to measure, let's make it do some real work:

```
> (time (nth-ld-power 1000))
Timing the evaluation of (nth-ld-power 1000)

User time    =        3.264
System time  =        0.039
Elapsed time =        3.384
Allocation   = 845193424 bytes
517 Page faults
GC time      =        0.020
12[...long number truncated here ...]
28745
```

So that's at least reasonable performance, I think.  These figures were for LispWorks on a 2013 macbook.  Obviously you can rewrite it without Tim's `iterate`, but I like it.

---

Here is a generalisation to the n-digit case.

```
(defun leading-decimal-digits (n m)
  ;; Return M leading digits from N: no sanity check
  (iterate peel ((q (truncate n (expt 10 (- (truncate (integer-length n)
                                                      (load-time-value (log 10 2)))
                                            (- m 1)))))
                 (digits '()))
    (multiple-value-bind (qq d) (truncate q 10)
      (cond
       ((zerop qq)
        (cons d digits))
       ((< qq 10)
         (list* qq d digits))
       (t
        (peel qq (cons d digits)))))))

(defun nth-power-with-leading-decimal-digits (n b leading)
  ;; Find the N'th occurrence of a power of B whose leading digits are
  ;; LEADING (a list of digits).  Return the value of B^P and P, the
  ;; power.
  (let ((nleading (length leading)))
    (iterate looking ((v 1)               ;value
                      (p 0)               ;power (so we can report it)
                      (c 0))              ;hit count
      (if (equal (leading-decimal-digits v nleading) leading)
          (let ((c+ (1+ c)))
            (if (= c+ n)
                (values v p)
              (looking (if (= b 2) (ash v 1) (* v b)) (1+ p) c+)))
        (looking (if (= b 2) (ash v 1) (* v b)) (1+ p) c)))))
```

So:

```
> (nth-power-with-leading-decimal-digits 2 2 '(1 2 8))
12855504354071922204335696738729300820177623950262342682411008
203

> (nth-power-with-leading-decimal-digits 2 3 '(2 7 8))
278954761343915929031866324148580803686773879062609352173281933430969939572023921519256921927359964084535215107090906022143908601839272147120823008337941481521208646465304746378648054338849857759629806700446921838039313884792762356955010344065298744426691826196079923777796821513452648753573059469525738664313409324728161550430310432705576201607066435772343529511415605105251217669677767280155388600975280964482318641251059803074701681895639266095014303466041595626938522373004626313927779288797843485898785327074755040298312905780373591994824646107875196292150692772609024142420597241695173176699988995274347532223981851419958515807471788303361043192244700492703668505222371093498892685289816397935636213340656919509760640657215827785179171568543835684943671352357398679232652259639784388841436515656182938820127024910154405205830179436914341715546500034485031465189386918271898229029201
1860
```

2^203 is the second occurrence of a power of 2 beginning with 128, and 3^1860 is the second occurrence of a power of 3 beginning 278.  The second one took 0.017 seconds.